# Почему не выводится список объектов Composite шаблона Компоновщик?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, компоновщик

Учу Java и разбираю паттерн Компоновщик. Вот какой код я написал:
В методе `public static void main(String[] args)` (сначала создал две папки и один файл):

```
Folder Folder1 = new Folder();
Folder1.setName("Folder1");
    
Folder Folder2 = new Folder();
Folder2.setName("Folder2");

FileTypeExe FileExe1 = new FileTypeExe();
FileExe1.setName("FileExe1");
    
//добавляем в папки файлы и другие папки
    Folder1.Add(Folder2);
    Folder1.Add(FileExe1);
    Folder2.Add(FileExe1);

    Folder1.print();
```

Результат:

```
  I'm FileExe1 - File
  I'm FileExe1 - File
```

Далее реализовал несколько классов. Первый - мы от него наследуем все остальные классы (как листовые - файлы, так и композиции - папки:

```
public class ElementDirectory {

public String nameObject = null;

public void setName(String nameObj) {
    this.nameObject = nameObj;
}

public void print() {
    this.Operation();
}

public void Operation() {
    System.out.println("Hello, I'm " + this.nameObject + " - ElementDirectory");
}

public void Add(ElementDirectory element) {
    System.out.println("ADD Directory");
}
```

Далее класс Лист (файл):

```
public class FileTypeExe extends ElementDirectory {

    @Override
    public void setName(String nameObj) {
        this.nameObject = nameObj;
    }

    @Override
    public void Operation() {
        System.out.println("Hello, I'm " + this.nameObject + " - File");
    }

}
```

И класс Композиции (папки):

```
public class Folder extends ElementDirectory {

    private final List<ElementDirectory> listElementDirectory = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void setName(String nameObj) {
        this.nameObject = nameObj;
    }

     //вызываем метод Operation(), который в классе Folder проходит по всем дочерним элементам 
     //в списке listElementDirectory и печатает их 
    @Override
    public void print() {
        for (ElementDirectory graphic : listElementDirectory) {
            graphic.print();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void Operation() {
        System.out.println("Hello, I'm " + this.nameObject + " - Folder");
    }

    @Override
    public void Add(ElementDirectory element) {
        listElementDirectory.add(element);
    }
}
```

Много кода, извините. Но я не пойму, по какой причине он не печатает структуру папок, они же тоже являются его потомками. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос.

Comment: У вас папка себя не печатает, она печатает только потомков. Если потомок - файл, он себя напечатает. Если потомок - папка, то читай комментарий с начала. Потому в итоге только файлы выводятся на печать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Комментарий в классе `Folder` не соответствует коду.  Метод `print` в классе `Folder` переопределён, поэтому для печати информации о папке нужно либо вызвать метод `print` класса-предка:

```java
// class Folder

@Override
public void print() {
    super.print();
    for (ElementDirectory graphic : listElementDirectory) {
        graphic.print();
    }
}
```

либо явно вызвать в этом методе `Operation()`

```java
// class Folder
@Override
public void print() {
    this.Operation();
    for (ElementDirectory graphic : listElementDirectory) {
        graphic.print();
    }
}
```